# Microsoft Intune - Can you cancel a request to wipe a device?

Tags: azure, mdm, intune

We have had a device stolen and so scheduled it for removal in Microsoft Intune.  It turns out that we indicated the wrong device.  Is there a way to cancel that action or do you have to wait for it to complete and then factory reset and re-enroll the device?

Answer (score 2):

You can't undo the remote task.

This has been answered before by Jon Lynn from Microsoft on the TechNet forums at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8a5dc4a-3a19-43c7-a936-f61f2bf01e14/cancel-remote-tasks-in-intune